# Can Firebase Auth.auth() functions be used to retrieve a GoogleSignIn user?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Within my app, I have 2 kinds of authentication:

1. Email address
2. Google Sign In

This is the relevant code for creating a user when they authenticate with their email address:

```
// Create the user
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (result, err) in
    // Check for errors
    if err != nil {
        
        // There was an error creating the user
        self.showError("Error creating user")
    }
    else {
        
        // User was created successfully, now store the first name and last name
        UserService.createProfile(userId: Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email) { (user) in
        }
    }
}
```

For users who authenticate with their email address, I'm already able to successfully call several functions for them all over my app. For example:

- To get the user's unique ID: `let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid`
- To check is a user is signed in when opening the app: `Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in }`

This is what I have in my `AppDelegate` to sign in a user with Google: `func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {}`

Is there a way to use those existing `Auth.auth()` functions for Google-authenticated users? Or would I need to add new code all over my app to account for these users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand, but will try to answer the most likely questions.

If you want to sign the Google-authenticated user in to Firebase, you can do so by calling `Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential)` as shown in the documentation on [authenticating with Firebase after signing in with Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin#3_authenticate_with_firebase).

Once a user signs in with Firebase Authentication (no matter with what provider) the `auth.currentUser` will bet set for them (and cleared when they sign out of Firebase), and `addStateDidChangeListener` will fire events for them.

Comment: The second point answers this question